# replace action bar up button with navigation slider when it is clicked

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have implemented a `navigation slider` in my app. In this slider I have four `fragments`: Home, Profile, Search, calculator. Don't worry about the naming conventions in selectItem method as I am only focusing on searchProgram as of now and don't have all my four fragments implemented
NavigationDrawer.class (Activity):

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomePage();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new SearchProgram();
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(HomeFragment.EXTRA_ITEM_INDEX, position);
            bundle.putString("username", userName);
            bundle.putString("access_token", access_token);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavItems[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
```

When I select search i am brought to a view which has an `action bar` with the navigation slider just like I wanted. When the user selects what they want to search for from the two spinners and clicks my own button called search I then start a `master detail flow` containing an expandable list.
Below is where i start my new activity from my searchProgram class(Fragment):

```
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<SportProgram> programList) {
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            String userName = getArguments().getString("username");
            String access_Token = getArguments().getString("accessToken");
            System.out.println("Search Program Test Username: " + userName);
            System.out.println("Search Program Test Access_Token: " + access_Token);
            extras.putString("username", userName);
            extras.putString("accessToken", access_Token);
            extras.putParcelableArrayList("programs", programList);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TrainingProgramListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

This view has an `action bar` with a back/up button and no navigation slider. When I click this button I am brought back to the previous view, i.e. the search view, however the action bar stays the same and still has the up button. Has anyone any idea on how to change the action bar to include the navigation slider like it did previously? also when I select the back/up button in my listActivity view I am replacing the current fragment as follows:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list_program, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
           //This is the back/up button
                case android.R.id.home:
                    fragment = new SearchProgram();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_home:
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, NavigationDrawer.class);
                    Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
                    homeIntent.putExtras(extras);
                    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);
                    System.out.println("HIT HOMEINTENT");
                    return true;
                case R.id.action_search:
                    fragment = new SearchProgram();
                    System.out.println("HIT SEARCH");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();//new Bundle();
              //  bundle.putString("username", userName);
               // bundle.putString("access_token", access_token);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerE, fragment).commit();

             //   fragment.getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

I have tried numerous possible solutions but keep falling short. All the examples i have found navigate from the navigationDrawer activity to a fragment and then another fragment but for me I am navigating from NavigationDrawer to a fragment->class->fragment. Any ideas please?

Comment: When going back to first activity, try calling `finish()` instead of  `new SearchProgram()` . I.e., just close the detail activity; you should find the previous activity in the background, with its drawer and so on.

Comment: yes!! thank you I have been stuck on this all morning and tried i don't know how many different ways!! thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stacking a detail activity on top of the main one which holds your drawer. To get back to the original activity, just close the last one using `finish()`, in your `onOptionsItemSelected()`.